# Pagination with Lister

Tags: pagination, atk4

I start using Agile Toolkit about 2 hours ago  and I can't solve one problem:
I need to add pagination to the main page of the blog and to the category page, that's my way:

```
    $lister = $this->add('Lister_Paginated',null,'Posts','Posts');
    $lister->setSource('posts');
    $lister->dq->where('published = FALSE')->order('date',true);
    $lister->addPaginator(5);
```

**template file**

```
<?Posts?>
   <?rows?>
    <?row?>
    <div class="post">
      <a href="/read/<?slug?>slug<?/?>.html"><img src="/uploads/img/<?previewIMG?>empty.jpg<?/?>" width="180" height="182"/></a><br />
      <span class="postTitle"><a href="/read/<?slug?>slug<?/?>.html"><?title?>Заголовок поста<?/?></a></span>
    </div>
    <?/row?>
   <?/rows?>
   <?$paginator?> 
  <?/Posts?>
```

But paginator doesn't work (content doesn't change)

Comment: You're using much of deprecated code. What version of ATK are you using? Try downloading newest version from github master branch and see if that's working there.

Comment: What's the name of template file? Maybe you're looking on wrong template file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a method in Lister. You should just take this method form [here](https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/Grid/Advanced.php#L143) and add into your project Lister

---

lib/Lister/Paginated.php

```
class Lister_Paginated extends CompleteLister {
    public $paginator;
    function addPaginator($ipp = 25, $options = null) {
        // adding ajax paginator
        if ($this->paginator) {
            return $this->paginator;
        }
        $this->paginator = $this->add('Paginator', $options);
        $this->paginator->ipp($ipp);
        return $this;
    }
    function defaultTemplate() {
        return array('view/lister/paginated');
    }
}
```

view/lister/paginated.html

```
<<?element?>ul<?/?> class="atk-lister <?$class?>" id="<?$_name?>">
<?rows?>
    <?row?>
        <<?row_element?>li<?/?> class="atk-lister-row <?$odd_even?>">
            <h3><?$name?></h3>
        </<?row_element?>li<?/?>>
    <?/row?>
    <?totals?>
    <<?row_element?>li<?/?> class="atk-lister-totals">
         Total: <?$row_count?> row<?$plural_s?>
    </<?row_element?>li<?/?>>
    <?/totals?>
<?/rows?>
<?$Content?>
<?$paginator?>     <---------------------------
</<?element?>ul<?/?>>
```

Usage:

```
$lister = $this->add('Lister_Paginated');
$lister->->addPaginator();
```

Comment: Can you give me a working example? I got new error - no such spot

Comment: add spot 'paginator' into lister template :) 
https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/Paginator/Basic.php#L199

Comment: I got new error :(
Application Error: Unable to find source for Paginator
BaseException, code: 0
atk4\lib\Paginator\Basic.php:83

Comment: thanks! Now i have no errors, but paginator doesn't change content :( please, see the topic question, I updated sources

Answer (score 0):

Which class do you use Lister or CompleteLister?

Don't use addPaginator cause it's quite old. Use $lister->add('Paginator')->ipp(2); It works with CompleteLister just fine.

Comment: I try to do it, but got a error: "Application Error: Spot is not found in owner's template" BaseException, code: 0

Additional information:

spot: paginator..... but I added this spot to the view :(

Comment: So you've added the spot to the wrong template. You need to put you <?$paginator?> spot to the appropriate template which specified in this particular class. Show us more code and we will have ability to help you.

Comment: Please, see question in this topic, I added logic and template code